# Confusion about Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to get information about selected files using `Dictionary`.But i  dont know how to do .This what i have so far .Could you please help

```
    Dictionary<string, FileInfo> list = new Dictionary<string, FileInfo>();

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                list[file] = new FileInfo(file);


                //fi = new FileInfo(file);
             //  listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Name :{0} FileSize : {1}", list.Name, list.Length.));

            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you here?

Comment: What does this have to do with generics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm assuming the commented out code is what is not working. The reason for that is you're trying to access properties of the dictionary and not **the property of a value in the dictionary**

this

```
listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Name :{0} FileSize : {1}", list.Name, list.Length.));
```

should be

```
listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Name :{0} FileSize : {1}", list[file].Name, list[file].Length));
```

First you have to retrieve the `FileInfo` object using the key (in this case the file name), then you can access the `Name` and `Length` properties of that instance. You `list` variable is of type dictionary and doesn't have a `Name` property. If you're using dot notation on the list like `list.Something` you're leaving out a level of indirection.

Comment: And without the random dot after "Length." :)

Comment: This is exactly what i need.Thank you so much.I will except as an answer afters 6 minutes later

Comment: @user2583511 np, glad I could help.

Comment: sory ı have forgatten